# WebApi request URL with empty string for value

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api, space

I have an WebApi endpoint for a database table in which 3 columns are PKs.
In some cases one of the keys is an empty string ('') in the database.

**Is it possible to supply this empty string value in my request URL?**

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Endpoint")]
public partial class APIUserCustomerController : BaseApiController<APIUserCustomer>
{
   [HttpDelete, Route("{UserName}/{CustomerNum}/{ShippingAddress}")]
   public HttpResponseMessage Delete(System.String UserName, System.String CustomerNum, System.String ShippingAddress) 
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

I've tried:

`DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum/`, which gives me `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`

as well as:

`DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum/%20` which gives me `Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.`

Is there a solution that I'm missing, or am I just SOL in regards to empty strings in my db?

Comment: What does `DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum//` do? or `DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum/%20/`

Comment: @Prescott, I don't think the code inside the method matters, the problem is that it's not finding the endpoint since the last piece of the URL is blank and therefore the api thinks it doesn't match any of the routes... but anyway, in this case it should delete the row in the database where User_Name = 'username' and Customer_Num = 'customerNum' and ShippingAddress = ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution in [optional parameters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Endpoint")]
public partial class APIUserCustomerController : BaseApiController<APIUserCustomer>
{
   [HttpDelete, Route("{UserName}/{CustomerNum}/{ShippingAddress?}")]
   public HttpResponseMessage Delete(System.String UserName, System.String CustomerNum, System.String ShippingAddress = "") 
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Now I can call

`DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum/shippingAddress` if I have the ship address

**OR**

`DELETE api/Endpoint/username/customerNum` if the ship address is blank.

Works great!!